# Firebase Authentication just works on one Device

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication for my flutter application. When I try to login with my virtual device it works, but if I try to login with my real device or Chrome, nothing happens if I press the button. There is no error in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a release apk and using the release version of the sha keys from firebase? It solved the problem for me when I had it.